# vuejs production cdn is not working https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js

Tags: vue.js, production

I am using vuejs as cdn in my web projects ( client side rendering )
my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="app">
    <h1>Test vue</h1>
    {{title}}
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my app.js

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data(){
    return{
        title:"mashoun"
    }
  }
});

app.mount('#app');
```

the error

```
vue.global.prod.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: 63
    at Vi (vue.global.prod.js:1:78062)
    at nu (vue.global.prod.js:1:119221)
    at Array.cu (vue.global.prod.js:1:119590)
    at zc (vue.global.prod.js:1:96277)
    at vue.global.prod.js:1:96681
    at zc (vue.global.prod.js:1:96691)
    at Wc (vue.global.prod.js:1:95664)
    at ja (vue.global.prod.js:1:117574)
    at vue.global.prod.js:1:122203
    at fu (vue.global.prod.js:1:122347)
```

yesterday every thing was good but now all my clients project are down and returning the same error
please help me ( paid )
mashoun.me@gmail.com

yesterday every thing was good but now all my clients project are down and returning the same error

Answer (score 0):

Besides the risk associated with the use of unpkg.com (it's unreliable and not production ready), the problem is that broad version range is used, and Vue 3.3 resulted in a breaking change. It can be narrowed to minor version that's known to be compatible:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Error stack can be debugged to template compiler, the use of `<script>` inside DOM template causes this, the application relied on undocumented behaviour that `script` elements are just ignored, which is evidently not the case for Vue 3.3.

Either application root should be separated from the script:

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Test vue</h1>
    {{title}}
  <div>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Or `<script>` needs to be moved to document head, and the execution needs to be postponed until [the document is ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/vanilla-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-whe).